Azure call automation with custom voice
I've created a voicebot using Azure call automation.
def get_chat_completions_async(system_prompt,user_prompt): 
    openai.api_key = AZURE_OPENAI_SERVICE_KEY
    openai.api_base = AZURE_OPENAI_SERVICE_ENDPOINT # your endpoint should look like the following https://YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME.openai.azure.com/
    openai.api_type = 'azure'
    openai.api_version = '2023-05-15' # this may change in the future
    
    # Define your chat completions request
    chat_request = [
        {"role": "system", "content": f"{system_prompt}"},
        {"role": "user", "content": f"In less than 200 characters: respond to this question: {user_prompt}?"}
    ]
  
    global response_content
    try:
        response = ChatCompletion.create(model=AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_MODEL,deployment_id=AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_MODEL_NAME, messages=chat_request,max_tokens = 1000)
    except ex:
        app.logger.info("error in openai api call : %s",ex)
       
    # Extract the response content
    if response is not None :
         response_content  =  response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    else :
         response_content=""    
    return response_content  


I seek to integrate a custom voice, which I have trained and deployed. According to the Microsoft docs, you can simply use the endpoint of the custom voice model for tts in your call automation app. However, this does not seem to work.
Does someone have previous experience integrating a custom voice into a call automation application using Azure?
I can use the endpoint for speech synthesis, but using the endpoint for call automation does not work - as in no generation happens - it does not give an error.

To integrate a custom voice into your Azure call automation application, you need to ensure that the custom voice endpoint is correctly utilized within the call automation process.
For Call Automation  we need callConnectionId  in Azure Communication Service
I followed   this MSDOC  to get callConnectionId of
Azure Communication Service.
POST https://contoso.communications.azure.com/calling/callConnections?api-version=2023-10-15
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{
  "callbackUri": "https://app.contoso.com/callback",
  "targets": [
    {
      "kind": "phoneNumber",
      "phoneNumber": {
        "value": "+919"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceCallerIdNumber": {
    "value": "+183"
  },
  "sourceDisplayName": "Contoso Support",
  "callIntelligenceOptions": {
    "cognitiveServicesEndpoint": "https://<your-cognitive-service-endpoint>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
  }
}


The below Python  code   is for customizing voice prompts with Play action using Azure Communication Services Call Automation SDK.

import os
import sys
from azure.communication.callautomation import (
    CallAutomationClient,
    CommunicationUserIdentifier
)

sys.path.append("..")

class CallAutomationCreateCallSample(object):

    connection_string = os.getenv("COMMUNICATION_CONNECTION_STRING")

    def create_call_to_single(self):
        callautomation_client = CallAutomationClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_string)

        # Creating a call
        user = CommunicationUserIdentifier("8:acs:123")
        callback_uri = "https://contoso.com/event"

        call_connection_properties = callautomation_client.create_call(
            target_participant=user,
            callback_url=callback_uri
        )

        # callconnection id of the call
        print(call_connection_properties.call_connection_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample = CallAutomationCreateCallSample()
    sample.create_call_to_single()






I referred to the MSDOC for the Azure Communication Call Automation client library for Python
  # callconnection id of the call
        call_connection_id = call_connection_properties.call_connection_id
        print(f"Call connection ID: {call_connection_id}")

  # Play the audio to the target participant
        call_connection.play_media(play_source=play_source, play_to=[target_participant])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample = CallAutomationCreateCallSample()
    
   
    call_connection_id, user = sample.create_call_to_single()

   
    audio_uri = "https://some.file.azure.com/sample.wav"
    play_source_cache_id = "string"  # Optional cache ID

    
    sample.play_audio_with_cache(call_connection_id, user, audio_uri, play_source_cache_id)



